# Почему возникает ошибка "failed to open stream" , "<script_name>.php' for inclusion"? PHP

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток
Прошу помочь:
При подключении файла относительно:

```
include '../controllers/Controller.php';
```

Возникли ошибки:

> Warning: include(../controllers/Controller.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/admin/views/View.php
>
> Warning: include(): Failed opening '../controllers/Controller.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/html/admin/views/View.php

(php ищет файл в другой папке, почему то)

При подключении файла абсолютно:

```
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/admin/controllers/Controller.php';
```

Все заработало, но так и не понял почему эти ошибки возникли.
Все файлы названы правильно, пути прописаны правильно тоже. (OS Linux)
Вопрос:
Почему возникли ошибки?
Почему скрипт искал файл не в папке куда я его направляю, а в папке отткуда я его вызвал?

Код:
путь /html/admin/controllers

```
class Controller {}
```

путь /html/admin/views

```
include '../controllers/Contoller.php';
class View extends Controller
{
    public function test()
    {
        echo __DIR__;
    }
}
```

пусть html/admin/index.php

```
include 'views/View.php';
$test = new View();
$test->test();
```

Comment: Дайте больше информации: из какого файла вызываете и и покажите структуру директорий, чтобы видно было эти два файла.

Comment: Спасибо большое, уже помогли разобраться

Comment: @ZhukovRoman строго говоря, все это есть в вопросе. И из какого файла вызывается, и какая структура директорий. Сообщения об ошибках рулят ;)

Comment: @Ипатьев в начальной версии вопроса были какие-то немного странные пути. В любом случае, вопрос уже закрыт.

Comment: @ZhukovRoman пути были те же самые :)

Comment: Спасибо ребят большое, вопрос переписал более развернуто, может поможет кому

Comment: @Ипатьев, меня сбили с толку звездочки `No such file or directory in /var/www/html/admin/**views/View.php**`

Comment: @ZhukovRoman, Я хотел выделить именно этот участок, но не получилось видимо

Answer (score 0):

Ошибки были в том, что файл родительского класса я подключал в дочернем классе, а include работает по принципу copy/paste, и копирует вместе с самим классом include с путем, который уже не правильный для этого файла, поэтому когда подключил файл абсолютно, то проблема исчезла.

При подключении одного файла к другому получилось:
index.php

```
include '../controllers/Controller.php'; 
//не находится т.к. controllers имеет не тот путь
class View
{
  public function test()
  {
      echo 'hello';
  }
}

$test = new View();
$test->test();
```